# Can't connect Canon 6D to my computer via USB cable

Tags: canon, usb, file-transfer, canon-6d

I can't download photos from my new Canon 6D via the USB cable. Cable is connected, but no new drive is detected in the system. Looks like Windows doesn't see a new device at all. How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Have you installed EOS Utility ? If you dont have the software take out the memory stick and plug it in directly to your laptop card read slot.

Comment: Page 369 of the manual explains this. The title is "Image Transfer Problems". Page 390 also describes downloading images in detail step by step.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? Are you connected to the internet with that Pc? Have you installed the drivers that came with the camera?

Comment: Well I aslo cant connect it via EOS utility, but I can connect it to PC (win 7 64 bit) and copy pic directly from the card (like disc), but the problem is i can't instal new softaware, coz my EOS utility does't find my 6D. PS: I have normal 6D without wifi and gps, so I cant realy turn wifi off, if I don't have it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TURN OFF WIFI.

I struggled with this too but if you disable wifi and reconnect the USB you should be fine.

Comment: If this is true, shouldnt you be complaining to Canon about this ? Sounds like a defect.

Comment: Sounds to me like a defect in Windows. But from another answer it seems Canon is no longer making the contents appear as a drive (which should not be affected by wifi unless trying to make the camera appear as a file share).

Comment: This occurs on OSX, too.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Windows problem — sounds like the camera just can't be in both sharing modes at once.

Comment: This is such a stupid bug!

Comment: @mattdm same on a Macbook :(

Answer (score 8):

You must install EOS Utility to download pictures directly from the camera. Your computer will not recognize it as a generic drive. EOS Utility will also give you the ability to shoot tethered and control the camera from your computer.

Your other option is to use a card reader instead.

> Does Canon not have a PTP/Mass Storage connection preference? Serious question; I haven't connected a Canon DSLR via USB, don't own one myself, so I've never checked the menu.

There is not a obvious PTP/Mass Storage device option with any of the following Canon cameras I have owned: Rebel XTi, 50D, 5DII, or 7D. Data exchange follows PIMA 15740-2000, with minor differences. But these differences preclude using the camera as a mass storage device without additional code. There are third party products that do the same thing EOS Utility does.

Comment: Does Canon not have a PTP/Mass Storage connection preference? Serious question; I haven't connected a Canon DSLR via USB, don't own one myself, so I've never checked the menu.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: There is not a obvious PTP/Mass Storage device option with any of the following Canon cameras I have owned: Rebel XTi, 50D, 5DII, or 7D. Data exchange follows PIMA 15740-2000, with minor differences. But these differences preclude using the camera as a mass storage device without additional code. There are third party products that do the same thing EOS Utility does.

Comment: Right, a Canon DSLR is not a disk drive to either Mac or Windows computers. Don't know why Canon decided to do it that way. The solution is to use DPP (the EOS utility)

Comment: @PatFarrell DPP is a separate application that is used for processing RAW(.crw, .cr2)/JPEG files, but it doesn't have the capability of communicating with the camera. EOS Utility is an entirely different application from DPP. Both, along with several other applications, are included on the CD provided with the camera.

Comment: @michael, thanks, I never can remember the names of all the parts. I also don't understand why there are so many parts, but for that, only Canon knows.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug.  On the Canon 6D, USB file transfer is disabled when Wi-Fi is enabled. Try disabling the Wi-Fi first. Good Luck!

Comment: Re “this is not a bug”: it is. It's a design level bug.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem myself when trying to download images from my new Canon 6D.

I'm a little picky, but:
1. I want to drag and drop from Windows Explorer, not a 3rd party program
2. I've have three card readers, but they don't recognize the newer/faster SD cards.  So I just want to plug my camera in.

Here's the fix:
 - turn off WiFi as mentioned above
 - download the new codec from Microsoft here:
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829

Enjoy dragging and dropping your photos with Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Disabled wifi on the 6D and opened up i photo and the images appeared.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, you might consider using a USB card reader to transfer the photos from the memory card to the computer. They aren't expensive.

(Admittedly, this doesn't fix the issue, but it is an alternative worth considering).

I can't remember when I last plugged my camera into the computer... I've used a card reader for years.

Unlike some cameras (which don't need a spcific device driver for the more recent versions of Windows to appear as a drive and use the USB mass storage driver that ships with Windows), Canon DSLRs need the EOS utility (supplied with the camera) to be installed to appear as a drive on the computer.

Comment: Canon DSLRs require EOS Utility. They will not function as a mass storage device.

Comment: Thanks... I wasn't sure because I don't use it. I've updated my answer to relect that.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason Canon does not have their cameras' memory appear as a normal USB device.

I have had no problems using DPP, Aperture 3 or Lightroom 4 between my 50D and my Macbook Pro, but I have to use a program.

The CF card in the camera does not simply appear as a device to the OS-X finder. Finder doesn't see the CF card.

I'm sure that Canon considers this a feature, not a bug.

Comment: My nephew's TV has an SDHC slot for camera cards (wish it has a CF). Plug in the card and you get an image browser show up. It's not a good one, but at least it works. It has USB and works the same there. But my 2 Canon cameras won't work. So I definitely call this a bug.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem try this way: connect the camera to computer with the usb cable and *then* turn the camera on. It worked for me, the computer will install the driver for you