# New SD XC card, works fine in T5i, Windows is prompting to format

Tags: canon, sdcard, sdxc

I used my new SDXC (64GB) card in my camera Canon T5i camera and took lot of photos (around 1000). For coping to laptop I removed the card from camera and inserted to my laptop SD card slot. Its prompting to Format the card.

Looks like my Windows 7 is not recognizing the file format in the card. Is there anyway to copy the files from this card to my Win7 laptop?

Comment: Windows doesn't know which filesystem your card was formatted with. Now I'm not a guru, but you should have 2 solutions: find out what filesystem your card is formatted and install the Windowse drivers for it; or, and this should be a last resort solution, try inserting the card on a Mac or a Linux system. These 2 should more likely to recognize your data. After you recover your data, format your card so that Windows recognizes it(NTFS or FAT32)...if you don't have a Linux computer, you can try to run it from a DVD without installing; this is handy(http://goo.gl/HsfUJj & https://goo.gl/xDg4vt)

Comment: I think you only need a new card reader, one that is SDXC compatible.

Comment: As someone pointed out, it is your card reader. You need an SDXC reader to read an SDXC card. An SD reader wont do it. Luckily, there are very cheap ones. I have 4 of them an paid under $10 each, that way there is one near each computer and one in the camera bag.

Comment: Please post your answer as answers!

Comment: Also see if you can use USB to have Windows 7 import that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For copying to my laptop I removed the card from camera and inserted to my **laptop SD card slot**. Its prompting to Format the card. Looks like my **Windows 7** is not recognizing the file format in the card.

Is your laptop an older laptop (5 or more years old)? If so, then WayneF's comment to your question is probably correct — your laptop's SD card reader is probably not SDXC-compatible. (See the [SD Association's primer on SDXC card compatibility](https://www.sdcard.org/consumers/sdxc_capabilities/)).

> Is there anyway to copy the files from this card to my Win7 laptop?

If your laptop's card reader is not SDXC-compatible, then you will have to buy a USB SD card reader. Ones supporting USB 3 (for fastest transfer speed), with multi-card support (Compact Flash, SD/SDHC/SDXC, and other less important formats) can be had for around $15 USD.

---

Regarding the [exFAT filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) itself, Windows is the *most* compatible operating system for that filesystem (Microsoft invented it, and holds the patents for exFAT).

- Apple has licensed exFAT from Microsoft, so OS X is 100% compatible with it, including reading, writing, and formatting media for exFAT.
- Linux is the least compatible with exFAT — it has no built-in support for exFAT. People have reverse-engineered the filesystem and have written exFAT filesystem drivers for Linux, but those drivers are not installed as part of the operating system.

  *Note*: If you use a Linux Live CD or Live Boot USB, after booting, you will first have to install `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` (assuming you're using Debian or Ubuntu Linux) before you can mount an exFAT drive or partition.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to copy the files from this card to my Win7 laptop?

Just connect your camera to the laptop with the USB cable the camera came with and copy the files this way

Comment: For a canon EOS camera such as the T5i, *EOS Utility* will also need to be installed. Data exchange follows the PIMA 15740-2000 protocol, but with minor differences. But these differences preclude using the camera as a mass storage device without additional code. There are third party products that do the same thing EOS Utility does.

Comment: Does this camera not present itself as a camera over USB without any extra Windows software?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No it does not. You need the additional code mentioned in the comment above. *EOS Utility* is included on the software disc that came with your T5i. Updates can be downloaded free at the Canon support website. It is fairly straightforward. Please see http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/34706/15871